# how to grab an image out of a DIV with C#

Tags: c#, css, email, html-parsing, attachment

is it possible to grab an image that is embedded in a div via C# and attach it to an email?

I've got the code for attaching and sending images via email, I just don't know how to get it to grab the specific item out of the div and email it.

The image varies with a previous user selection so I can't just apply a static address of an image.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are trying to parse?

Comment: What's an *"image embedded in a div"*?

Comment: <div id="divProof" class="label" style="text-align: center;">
<img src="http://www.website.com/order/proxy/proxy.aspx?proof={f16b0786-4213-46e1-b7e5-126e898154b1}-1.jpg&amp;Size=SMALL" class="proof">
</a>
<br>
<img src="http://www.website.com/order/proxy/proxy.aspx?proof={f16b0786-4213-46e1-b7e5-126e898154b1}-2.jpg&amp;Size=SMALL" class="proof">
</a>
<br>
</div>

Comment: I would like to grab those image files and attach them to an email. The easiest way if it works would be to just specifiy the DIV name "Proof" in the C# code and tell it to grab the image file from there. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab image from inbound email?

Read more about [MIME format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME): all images in email message are encriped in base64 format in MIME message. To grab your image you need to parse your emailmessage, read base64 string, wich encript your image, and decoding this string like this:

`var byties = Convert.FromBase64String(Body)`

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't being clear. I don't want to grab an image from an inbound email, I want to grab an image off a website (this image is embedded in a DIV and varies depending on a user selection on a previous page) and attach this image to an email and send it off. The important part is how I can grab this image file out of the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using the microsoft html control, read the document and use the DOM to get the url of the image, download it using the http and then attach it to your email

for reference

[How to download the image](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/cs_imagedownload.aspx)

[Reading the Dom from visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) and `HttpWebRequest`.